# What is the Authorized Javascript Origin for a webapp powered by Google Script?

Tags: authentication, google-apps-script, oauth-2.0, google-signin, credentials

I'm building a webapp with the Google Script engine. Te application uses the Sign in With Google button to log in, so I need a project with a Credential in the Google Cloud Platform which asks me to introduce a domain in the Authorized JavaScript Origin field. Domains of the kind xxx.googleusercontent.com used to work but now they appear to be forbidden.
[Google Cloud Platform Credentials](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xskH.png)

Since the app is hosted by Google Script platform, I've tried the URI https://script.google.com, but it does not work. It keeps on saying:

*Not a valid origin for the client: https://n-lvkfgw4qjsttvut5eeun3inieub2bbse7ukpiti-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com has not been registered for client ID 577491057122-qlfn0853m85t0u7gsd4rr69rulghts54.apps.googleusercontent.com. Please go to https://console.developers.google.com/ and register this origin for your project's client ID."
​
error: "idpiframe_initialization_failed"*

Does anybody know anything about this issue?

Comment: Have you tried registering the link given in the error? 577491057122-qlfn0853m85t0u7gsd4rr69rulghts54.apps.googleusercontent.com.  I know this sounds kind of dumb but I did a similar thing with dropbox and it worked.

Comment: 577491057122-qlfn0853m85t0u7gsd4rr69rulghts54.apps.googleusercontent.com seems to be the client ID. The domain to register should be https://n-lvkfgw4qjsttvut5eeun3inieub2bbse7ukpiti-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com, shoudn't it? And how can I register that domain in the developer console?

Anyway, they say, explicitely, that anything with googleusercontent.com is a forbidden domain.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56803054/1595451

Answer (score 3):

#### Answer:

*There was a discussion about this on a bug reported on Google's Issue Tracker - this has become disallowed due to security concerns. There is, therefore, no current way to use an Apps Script Web App as a JavaScript origin at all.*

#### More Information:

The bug report in question:

- [Fail to Add *.googleusercontent.com into Authorized JavaScript origins](https://issuetracker.google.com/170740549)

An investigation was conducted as there was seemingly no public information about the change. On March 31st 2021, a Googler eventually responded, explaining the reason for the change and closed the issue as intended behaviour:

> Current [policies for use of OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/policies) require apps to use secure JavaScript origins and redirects on [domains that you own](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/policies?hl=en#domains). While the use of certain shared domains is allowed (e.g. Firebase apps running on *.web.app), the use of `*.googleusercontent.com` as OAuth origins or redirect URIs is blocked in order to ensure the security and privacy of user accounts.
>
> Documentation has been updated at [Redirect URI validation rules](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#uri-validation) and [JavaScript origin validation rules](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/javascript-implicit-flow#origin-validation) has been updated in order to reflect this:
>
> > Host domains cannot be “googleusercontent.com”.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping clarify the issue. So I understand that I can no longer use the "Sign in with Google" button with the Google Script web application, right?

Comment: @Maatinspicasso Effectively, no. If you wish to identify the user to perform specific tasks you should instead use the Web App deployment options and built in methods.